# I am using d3 to visualize some nodes and links. I want to be able to fadeout other circles (nodes) when I hover over one circle

Tags: d3.js

Currently I can highlight the node which is on the mouse focus by changing the node's stroke. However I also want to be able to fade out all other nodes(by making their strokes more transparent). The only issue that I have, is that I don't know how can I refer to all other nodes which are not on the mouse focus. 
I would prefer to include that in the same functions that I have for mouseover and mouseout.

```
var nodes = svg.selectAll(".node")
                  .data(graph.nodes)
                  .enter().append("g")
                  .attr("class", "node").
                  on("mouseover", mouseover)
                  .on("mouseout", mouseout);

function mouseover() {

d3.select(this).select("circle").transition().style("stroke-width","9");
```

}

```
function mouseout() {
d3.select(this).select("circle").transition().style("stroke","#0006B3").style("stroke-width","1");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
function mouseover() {
//this will make all the circle fade out
d3.selectAll("circle").style("opacity", 0.2);
//this will make our circle opacity 1
d3.select(this).select("circle").style("opacity", 1)

d3.select(this).select("circle").transition().style("stroke-width","9");
}
```

Now on mouse out make all the circle opacity 1:

```
function mouseout() {
    //this will make all the circle fade out
    d3.selectAll("circle").style("opacity", 1);
   d3.select(this).select("circle").transition().style("stroke","#0006B3").style("stroke-width","1");
}
```

Hope this helps!